# Does ticking Remember Me or Keep Me Signed In have something to do about Google Chrome knowing my Facebook Password?

Tags: google-chrome

Does ticking "Remember Me" or "Keep Me Signed In" have something to do about Google knowing my Facebook Password (because they are the owner of Chrome Browser)?

By the way, I'm not syncing my passwords, only other stuffs but not passwords.

Comment: If you assume that Google's claims about are true, then Google doesn't ever know your passwords. Even if you sync passwords.  Any passwords you sync are encrypted against your account password or the passphrase you define.  Why do you think Google knows your password?

Comment: We had a similar question about Chrome and this very topic recently.  I believe this to be spam so I will flag it as such for that very reason.  Infact  it was this very user who ask this non-question earlier and that was also closed.  [here](http://superuser.com/questions/755572/everybody-is-asking-about-passwords-being-saved-inside-browser-password-managers)

Answer (score 2):

Ticking "Remember Me" or "Keep Me Signed In" will set a cookie in your browser.  It does not save your password anywhere.

Comment: Does that mean Google have no ways of knowing what I typed in Chrome even if they are the owner of Chrome? So it is not sent by the browser to their server secretly (backdoor).

Comment: "no ways of knowing" is pretty broad......

Comment: @MeWowlol You're getting into the realm of speculation/opinion/conspiracy. Certainly Google might have the capability of doing this, but it's anyone's guess of how much they take advantage of their capabilities.